# Adding label color close to each row in UITableView Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with different sections and rows. I want to have different label or image like a icone close each cell but I don't know why it's looks like this picture:

Also scrolling changed the size of labels!

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,0,40,40)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

}
else if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,0,40,40)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];    }
else if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,0,40,40)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];    }
else{

}
[[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: where is your section condition ?

Comment: just pass [cell.imageview setBackgroundColor:blackColor];

Comment: @NikhilBansal but its not imageview

Comment: ok then use this  [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:blackColor];

Comment: Scrolling did not nessessarily change the size of the label but apparently did change the sequence of the subiews? It looks as if the standard lable is on top of the 40/40 coloured lable. Why do you use a UI lable for this pupose anyway? You could simply use an empty UIView and set its background colour accordingly.

Comment: What about creating simple plain coloured 40x40 png images and assigning those to cell.imageView.image? Should be saver in the context of the cell's layout automatisms.

Comment: If you use ARC then your (current) implmentation of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier works fine. However, there is no need to allocate a new coloured image every time when a cell is reused. In your (current version of) cellForRowAtIndexPath you do not alternate the colour of the image at all. 
However, you may want to add a laoutSubviews method to your subclass where you layout all the subviews that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In your code when user scroll table, labels created many times! You must check if color label already exist in cell and then set color

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
int colorLabelTag = 9999;
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];     
}

// Because table cells are reusing we must check is label already in cell
UILabel* label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:colorLabelTag];
// If no - we create label
if (!label) {
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,0,40,40)];
    label.tag = colorLabelTag;
    [cell addSubview:label];
}

if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];        
}
else if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
[[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want more cusotomizing than this there is no need for subclassing the cell. 
Let me give it a try:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
    NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // If you need to add more custom views then create them here. E.g.: 
        UILabel *myLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,200,20,20)];
        myLable.text = @"Some Value";
        label.tag = 101; // use anything but 1. Better use a constant expression.
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLable];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
      case 1: 
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
        break;

      case 2: 
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
        break;

      case 3: 
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
        break;
    }  

   UILabel* theLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:101]; // again, a constant is of better style here. 
   if (theLabel  { // it must exist. However, it is good practice to check upon that. 
    label.text = @"someOtherValue";
   }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];

    // you may need to layout your subviews here. 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: but after that I want to add another label I need to customising

Comment: I did a lot of subclassing myself before I realized that it is not really required just to add a lable here and there. However, the advantage of subclassing is that you can subclass the layoutSubviews method too.

Comment: If you want to add a lable then you can to that as sree charan just suggested. You can tag it and check whether it exists or not. This is because cells that disappear from screen are reused. Therefore they may already have that lable. However, I will amend my answer in order to support more subviews.